# ES6 classes - Wrong constructor and setters behavior

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to use `setters` insight `ES6 classes` to call some method automatically when some properties of a instance are changed.

I wrote this:

```
class Some {
  constructor () {
    this.xPos = 0;
    this.yPos = 0;
  }

  set xPos (value) {
    console.log(`xPos ${this.xPos}`);
  }

  set yPos (value) {
    console.log(`yPos ${this.yPos}`);
  }
}

let some = new Some();
```

But the console outputs:

```
xPos undefined
yPos undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have getters for `xPos` and `yPos`, so why you get undefined.

This `this.xPos = 0;` calls setter for `xPos`, but when you want to write the value, it is going to find a variable or a getter for it, but you don't have any of them. In you case you need to work with value, or write a getter for it.

In the example I am working through `getters` and `setters`. In `setter` I set the value for properties and read throw `getter`. The `getter` returns the propertie's value.

```js
class Some {

  constructor () {
    this.xPos = 0;
    this.yPos = 0;
  }

  set xPos (value) {
    this.xPosProp = value;
    console.log(`xPos ${this.xPos}`);
  }

  set yPos (value) {
    this.yPosProp = value;
    console.log(`yPos ${this.yPos}`);
  }
  
  get xPos () {
    return this.xPosProp;
  }

  get yPos () {
    return this.yPosProp;
  }
}

let some = new Some();
```

Comment: So if I provide setter for some prop I must provide getter for it?
Should It be something like:
get xPos(){return this.xPos}
?

Comment: @animatio if you want to read the value pass to that setter, you must

Comment: @animatio and also here you need a property , if you want to store the data